# Cannot use 'PhpParser\Node\Scalar\String' as class name as it is reserved

Tags: laravel-5, composer-php, php-parse-error

When I use the composer to install Laravel 5 I get this error:

> Cannot use 'PhpParser\Node\Scalar\String' as class name as it is
>   reserved in
>   /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/learnlaravel5/vendor/nikic/php-parser/lib/PhpParser/PrettyPrinter/Standard.php
>   on line 86

[Image of the error here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ptSqT.png)

What is wrong?

Comment: What version of PHP are you using? (You can run `php -v` on the command line)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

*I assume you are using PHP7 as you wouldn't get this error otherwise (?).*

In PHP7 `String` is now a reserved keyword along with [some others](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.other-reserved-words.php). The PHP-Parser library used this keyword but was since [fixed in April 2015](https://github.com/nikic/PHP-Parser/issues/192). Try upgrading the PHP-Parser library, this should help.

Comment: PHP 7.0.0 (cli) (built: Dec  2 2015 13:06:23) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2015 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.0.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2015 Zend Technologies

Comment: SamV how do I upgrade the PHP-Parser library?

Comment: @AndrewKoper upgrading your composer entry to the version 2.1.0 should do the trick, don't forget to run `composer update`.

Comment: which composer entry?

Answer (score 6):

Following @SamV's answer, this problem may cause the `post-create-project-cmd` not to run. As a result you won't have `.env` file. To compensate for this you can run them manually from within your project folder in the terminal as follows.

```
cp .env.example .env
php artisan key:generate
```

You can see what scripts are actually being run by checking the scripts section of the `composer.json` file.

Answer (score 0):

In php 7 'String' is a special Class name.
The best solution is to upgrade your Laravel version.
But if you need to use older version, you can replace String with `String_`
At

> /vendor/psy/psysh/src/Psy/CodeCleaner/MagicConstantsPass.php

on line 19, you will find two `String` , just replace them with `String_`.