# when I use composer to install laravel I'm getting error

Tags: php, laravel

PHP Fatal error:

> Cannot use 'PhpParser\Node\Scalar\String' as class name as it is reserved in /opt/lampp/htdocs/makemykareer/vendor/nikic/php-parser/lib/PhpParser/PrettyPrinter/Standard.php on line 86

I'm using php 7 and ubuntu 16.04

Comment: Try upgrading the PHP-Parser library. use `composer update`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot use 'PhpParser\Node\Scalar\String' as class name as it is reserved](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34200096/cannot-use-phpparser-node-scalar-string-as-class-name-as-it-is-reserved)

Answer (score 1):

Try upgrading your PHP-Parser library by upgrading your composer version